# how to get repository information for tomcat8 and installation on fedora 22

Tags: fedora

How can I get repository informantion in fedora22 for installing apache tomcat 8
I have seen many sites url but after trying wget it is showing that content not found.
How to download add install tomcat 8 in fedora22

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following steps

Opended http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi
then select appropriate mirror > under Binary Distributions
right click and open tar.gz (under core) in new tab.

copy the address in address bar which is like 
then open your linux shell or telnet

then `#wget http://apache.mirrors.hoobly.com/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.26/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.26.tar.gz`

it will download the file
next untar file like
 `#tar -xvf apache-tomcat-8.0.26.tar.gz`

then goto bin folder of tomcat
`# cd apache-tomcat-8.0.26/bin`

and start it
`# ./startup.sh`
check it by opening `http://ipaddress:8080`
it will display tomcat